# Is a local variable trainable by default or not?

Tags: variables, tensorflow

When I walk through the guide https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/variables, I'm confused with the description below (bold):

> By default every `tf.Variable` gets placed in the following two
>   collections:
>
> - `tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES` --- variables that can be shared across multiple devices,
> - `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` --- variables for which TensorFlow will calculate gradients.
>
> **If you don't want a variable to be trainable**, add it to the `tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES` collection instead. For example, the following snippet demonstrates how to add a variable named `my_local` to this collection:

```
my_local = tf.get_variable("my_local", shape=(), collections [tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])`
```

> Alternatively, you can specify `trainable=False` as an argument to
>   `tf.get_variable`:

```
my_non_trainable = tf.get_variable("my_non_trainable", shape=(), trainable=False)
```

But when I create a local variable, it's added into the collection `tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` automatically, which would mean it is trainable. So, is a local variable trainable or not?

Comment: What do you mean "when I create a local variable"? How do you create it? Do you specify the `tf.GraphKeys.LOCALVARIABLES` in the `collections` argument?

Comment: @bluesummers I create a local variable with `my_local = tf.get_variable("my_local", shape=(), collections [tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES])`, anyway, I think @kafman has eliminated my confusion, the documentation in the tensorflow guide is indeed confusing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is indeed confusing. By default, a local variable is also added to the collection of trainable variables. You can check this by inspecting `tf.trainable_variables()`. So, it looks like to make a local variable *not* trainable, it is not enough to add it to the `LOCAL_VARIABLES` collection, but you need the keyword `trainable=False`.

Here is a short script that shows that both the local and global variable are updated in the training loop:

```
import tensorflow as tf

my_local = tf.get_variable("my_local", shape=(), collections=[tf.GraphKeys.LOCAL_VARIABLES],
                           initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1.0))
my_global = tf.get_variable("my_global", shape=(),
                            initializer=tf.constant_initializer(2.0))

target_value = tf.constant(4.0)
loss = tf.abs(my_local + my_global - target_value)
optim = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1.0).minimize(loss)

for v in tf.trainable_variables():
    print(v.name)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    sess.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    print("local init: ", sess.run(my_local))
    print("global init: ", sess.run(my_global))
    for i in range(2):
        _, l = sess.run([optim, loss])
        print("loss {:.4f}".format(l))
        print("local: ", sess.run(my_local))
        print("global: ", sess.run(my_global))
```

which prints

```
my_local:0
my_global:0
local init:  1.0
global init:  2.0
loss 1.0000
local:  1.9999996
global:  2.9999995
loss 1.0000
local:  1.9473683
global:  2.9473681
```

The value of `my_local` does not change if you set `trainable=False` in the call to `tf.get_variable`.